# Can you disable the black lock in custom games?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

Me and my friend do 1v1s in custom games but as soon as we start the hatch opens making it so that the survivor can easily escape. And if the killer closes it endgame starts. Is there a way to disable the hatch entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and it looks like there is absolutely no way to remove the hatch. The best you can do is a gentlemen's agreement to not interact with the hatch.